# Rearrange javascript array base on condition

Tags: javascript

Rearrange javascript array value, user whose result is true they must be display from last indexes.

if result value is true then their object should start from the last object e.g Zahir and harman should be last two object.

```
const scorecard = [
  {
        name: "Zahir",
        score: 23,
        result: true,
  }, 
  {
        name: "Kabir",
        score: 13,
        result: false
  },
  {
        name: "Kunal",
        score: 29
  },
  {
        name: "Arnav",
        score: 42,
        result: false
  },
  {
        name: "Harman",
        score: 19,
        result: true
  },
  {
        name: "Rohit",
        score: 41
  },
  {
        name: "Rajan",
        score: 34
  }
];

 scorecard.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.result == true)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
});

console.log("s", scorecard)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just return `true` and `false` instead of `-1` and `0`.

```js
const scorecard = [
  {
        name: "Zahir",
        score: 23,
        result: true,
  }, 
  {
        name: "Kabir",
        score: 13,
        result: false
  },
  {
        name: "Kunal",
        score: 29
  },
  {
        name: "Arnav",
        score: 42,
        result: false
  },
  {
        name: "Harman",
        score: 19,
        result: true
  },
  {
        name: "Rohit",
        score: 41
  },
  {
        name: "Rajan",
        score: 34
  }
];

 scorecard.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a?.result == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});

console.log("s", scorecard)
```

Comment: @simon Is this what you want?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine. Just replace your "if" syntax for like this:

```
if (!a.result) return -1;
else return 0;
```

Or optimise code like this:

```js
const scorecard = [
  {
        name: "Zahir",
        score: 23,
        result: true,
  }, 
  {
        name: "Kabir",
        score: 13,
        result: false
  },
  {
        name: "Kunal",
        score: 29
  },
  {
        name: "Arnav",
        score: 42,
        result: false
  },
  {
        name: "Harman",
        score: 19,
        result: true
  },
  {
        name: "Rohit",
        score: 41
  },
  {
        name: "Rajan",
        score: 34
  }
];

 scorecard.sort(({result}) => !result ? -1 : 0);

console.log("s", scorecard)
```

also, you can use `.reverse()` (more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse))

like this:

```js
const scorecard = [
  {
        name: "Zahir",
        score: 23,
        result: true,
  }, 
  {
        name: "Kabir",
        score: 13,
        result: false
  },
  {
        name: "Kunal",
        score: 29
  },
  {
        name: "Arnav",
        score: 42,
        result: false
  },
  {
        name: "Harman",
        score: 19,
        result: true
  },
  {
        name: "Rohit",
        score: 41
  },
  {
        name: "Rajan",
        score: 34
  }
];

 scorecard.sort(({result}) => result ? -1 : 0);

console.log("s", scorecard)
console.log("s reverse", scorecard.reverse())
```

But I prefer you the first option

Comment: _"Zahir and harman should be last two object"_.  For you, In first case, its "Rajan" & "Rohit". and in second case, its "Zahir" and "Kabir". This is not what OP wants.